# Rendering blade components via AJAX doesn't initiate component attributes and methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Blade Component class like this:

```php
    class RolesSelect extends Component
    {
    
        public $roles;
        public $user;
    
        public function __construct($roles = null, $user = null)
        {
          //... some logic goes here (irrelevant)
        }
    
        public function isSelected($user,$role)
        {
            // ... some logic
        }
        
        public function render()
        {
            return view('components.roles-select');
        }
    }
```

When I render my component as usual `<x-roles-select></x-roles-select>` everything goest fine.

But here starts the problem: when I load the component via AJAX, I use the `view('components.roles-select')->render()`. And the component can't see the `isSelected` method anymore.

It throws this error: `Undefined variable: isSelected`

I tried to research the Blade and Component classes, but only came this far:

```php
$roleSelect = new RolesSelect($roles, $user);
$roleSelect->resolveView()->render();
```

I can access everything, but the `isSelected` method.

Answer (score 0):

I was close enough. Dabbled a bit with the code, and got it working!

In my controller (or just the route method), you have to initialise the component class, and pass it's data to the view like this:

```
$roleSelect = new RolesSelect($roles, $user);

if (request()->wantsJson()) {
    return response()->json([
        'content' => $roleSelect->resolveView()->with($roleSelect->data())->render()
    ],200);
}
```